# How to pass parameters of Phonegap javascript for ios plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

My requirement is to create phonegap component for iPad.
I am using XCode 4.2 and Phonegap 1.9.0 SDK.

I had set of native iOS Class files which needs to be used for phonegap.
I created the Plugin class for the iOS Native Code. My code also contain the javascript code. I need to call the iOS code through javascript code.

My iOS code contains the parameter as Array. We can iterate the array as objectAtIndex 1, 2 etc. How to call the native code from written plugin class with parameters below

Plugin Code:

```c
- (void) myMethod:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
  NSString* callbackId = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];

  CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
  NSString* javaScript = nil;

  @try {
    NSString* myarg = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];

    if (myarg != nil) {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK];
        javaScript = [pluginResult toSuccessCallbackString:callbackId];
    } 
  } @catch (id exception) {
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_JSON_EXCEPTION    messageAsString:[exception reason]];
    javaScript = [pluginResult toErrorCallbackString:callbackId];
  }

    [self writeJavascript:javaScript];
}
```

Native Code:

```c
-(NSArray*)nativeFunctionDisplay:(NSArray*)args;
```

I need to call this native code in plugin class

The parameters values are taken from javascript functions. In js file I need to call the plugin class and need to pass the parameters.

Javascript.js:

```js
var arg1;
var arg2;
var arg 3;

PluginClass.callNativeFunction(<How to pass the arguments here>)
```

I saw the many samples, but they are tried for getting initial things such as alert message as SUCCESS.

Can you please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arg1;
var arg2;
var arg3;

PluginClass.callNativeFunction([arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

You just have to create a array in Javascript.

Rohde Fischer wrote some good examples for iOS

https://github.com/rohdef/PGPlugins/blob/3_Arguments/www/pluginExample.js

Comment: Thanks Christian. Can we pass the arguments without successcallback and errorcallback. If yes can we return the arguments in successcallback method?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you won't provide a success cllback, how do you want to send a value to that callback?

Comment: Actually i am passing the int value to the plugin class. Where this value is passedd to native code parameter. This native code returns the int value. How can i take the return value from native code into plugin? then i want to pass this to javascript code. For this, how the success callback can be used? please help on this....